# XSL FO continued / running tables, markers in footer

Tags: xml, pdf-generation, xsl-fo, marker, xmltable

I am using markers and "retrieve-table-marker" in XSL-FO to create footers in a PDF transformation.

I need a solution where a one-column table has a "clean" footer and a multi-column table has a footer with added text ("continued") before each column-break. The added text should only be applied before the page break IF the table breaks between columns.

My current code *almost* does this. It works well for multi-column tables, but for a one-column table the "continued" text is added even though the table does not break.

The code:

```
  <fo:table-body>
    <fo:table-row>
      <fo:table-cell>
        <fo:block>
          <fo:marker marker-class-name="footer-continued">(continued)</fo:marker>
        </fo:block>
        <fo:block>
          <xsl:text>Contents</xsl:text>
        </fo:block>
        <fo:block>
          <fo:marker marker-class-name="footer-continued"></fo:marker>
        </fo:block>
      </fo:table-cell>
    </fo:table-row>
  </fo:table-body>

  <fo:table-footer>
    <fo:table-row>
      <fo:table-cell>
        <fo:block>
          <fo:retrieve-table-marker retrieve-class-name="footer-continued" 
                                    retrieve-position="first-including-carryover"
                                    retrieve-boundary-within-table="table"/>
        </fo:block>
      </fo:table-cell>
    </fo:table-row>
  </fo:table-footer>
```

Answer (score 3):

Alright, this worked for me:

I swapped

```
retrieve-position="first-including-carryover"
```

for

```
retrieve-position-within-table="last-ending-within-page"
```

Comment: Do you use antenna house ?
Beacause I use fop and I always get a error message

Comment: The OP was probably using XslFormatter; at that time FOP did not support `fo:retrieve-table-marker` elements, but it supports them now (FOP version >= 2.0), albeit with some limitations.